# Does the Windows Composition API support 2.5D projected rotation?

Tags: animation, uwp, rotation, windows-composition-api, 2.5d

I have started to use the Windows Composition API in UWP applications to animate elements of the UI.

Visual elements expose RotationAngleInDegrees and RotationAngle properties as well as a RotationAxis property.

When I animate a rectangular object's RotationAngleInDegrees value around the Y axis, the rectangle rotates as I would expect but in a 2D application window, it does not appear to be displaying with a 2.5D projection.

Is there a way to get the 2.5D projection effect on rotations with the composition api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the sample that @BarryWang pointed me to demonstrates it is necessary to apply a TransformMatrix to the page (or a parenting container) before executing the animation to get the 2.5D effect with rotation or other spatial transformation animations with the composition api.

```
    private void UpdatePerspective()
    {
        Visual visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(MainPanel);

        // Get the size of the area we are enabling perspective for
        Vector2 sizeList = new Vector2((float)MainPanel.ActualWidth, (float)MainPanel.ActualHeight);

        // Setup the perspective transform.
        Matrix4x4 perspective = new Matrix4x4(

                    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

                    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

                    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f / sizeList.X,

                    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        // Set the parent transform to apply perspective to all children
        visual.TransformMatrix =

                           Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(-sizeList.X / 2, -sizeList.Y / 2, 0f) *      // Translate to origin

                           perspective *                                                            // Apply perspective at origin

                           Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(sizeList.X / 2, sizeList.Y / 2, 0f);         // Translate back to original position
    }
```

Comment: You should also be able to do this using XAML's PerspectiveTransform3D property 
`
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid" >
        <Grid.Transform3D>
            <PerspectiveTransform3D Depth="1000" />
        </Grid.Transform3D>
....
</Grid>
`

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake, awesome, I didn't realize that was in Windows 10 XAML or that it also worked in conjunction with the Composition APIs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends to the effect that you want to have. There is a fluent design app sample on GitHub and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples) is the link. You will be able to download the demo from the [store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N1H8CZHBPXB). And you can get some idea from depth samples. For example, flip to reveal shows a way to rotate a image card and you can find source code from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/blob/4086e727f08714bec3520ff1a1782c5cc822f650/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2010586/TransitionAnimation-FlipToReveal/FlipToReveal.xaml.cs). For more details please check the sample and the demo.

In general, the animation is to rotate based on X axis:

> rectanglevisual.RotationAxis = new System.Numerics.Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f);

And then use rotate animation to rotate based on RotationAngleInDegrees.

It is also possible for you to do this directly on XAML platform by using [PlaneProjection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/3-d-perspective-effects) from image control.

Comment: Thanks @BarryWang for pointing me to a sample. I was already using an animation based on RotationAngleInDegrees to rotate a card around the Y axis.  However by default that rotation does not apply a perspective projection. The secrete seems to be that for the 2.5D projection effect you also need to apply a TransformMatrix to the page.

Comment: @HoloSheep Exactly. If that effect is what you want, the TransformMatrix is actually the answer.